# Server and localhost server time are different

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-4

Any please help me my multiple projects are running on glassfish server, it is installed on Godaddy server, so when i deploy any project my server time changed from my localhost server, My server time show time GMT but i want it must show in PKT, after deploying any project it should not be changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the timezone as JVM option in your *domain.xml* file by adding following option:

```
<jvm-options>-Duser.timezone=Asia/Karachi</jvm-options>
```